MAUI C# HttpClient Connection problems
C# Maui code :
var uri = new Uri("https://www.google.pl/");
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();                
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

I have a problem in Maui, the program freezes on this line:
var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

it doesn't go any further, it doesn't hit "catch"
In Android, I have added manifests about the Internet, but the problem also occurs in WM
When I solve this problem, I would also like to connect to http addresses, and this will probably be the next problem
Manifest is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<manifest xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
  <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true">
  </application> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> 
</manifest>

Solution:
var response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;


Did you add internet permission?

"I would also like to connect to http addresses and this will probably be the next problem" - there is no such thing as "connecting to http addresses" and let's focus one question on one problem.

@Selvin I am not too familiar with Maui but shouldn't a missing permission cause an exception to be thrown in such case? That's what I would expect at least. I also interpret "I have added mainifests about the Internet" to mean OP added those permissions.

Kamil: is that happening always or only sometimes? I could imagine there's some port exhaustion if maui isn't completely different in HttpClient behavior.

Are you using .Wait or .Result anywhere in your code?

@Charlieface are you going for a deadlock? That kind of sounds even more probable than port exhaustion.

is that happening always or only sometimes? Always
mainifest :







Have you checked the internet speed, is it quite slow? You can also try testing it with another device to see if this happens.

You can try accessing the google address in the browser of the Android emulator to see if it works.
